# How to use Listview virtual mode for accessing database?

Tags: c#

I have this code retrieving data from a database but my problem is that it only shows the last item on my `ListViewItem`. Here is the code:

```
    private void patientLvw_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {

        cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM PATIENTS ORDER BY PATIENTS.PatientNo;", conn);


        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            String patientNo = ""; ;
            String lastName = "";
            String firstName = "";
            String middleInitial = "";
            String age = "";
            String address = "";
            String type = "";
            String status = "";
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
            {
                patientNo = reader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
            }

            if (!reader.IsDBNull(1))
            {
                lastName = reader.GetString(1);
            }

            if (!reader.IsDBNull(2))
            {
                firstName = reader.GetString(2);
            }
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(3))
            {
                middleInitial = reader.GetString(3);
            }
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(4))
            {
                age = reader.GetInt32(4).ToString();
            }
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(5))
            {
                address = reader.GetString(5);
            }
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(6))
            {
                type = reader.GetString(6);
            }
            if (!reader.IsDBNull(7))
            {
                status = reader.GetBoolean(7).ToString();
            }

            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(patientNo);


            e.Item.SubItems.Add(lastName);

            e.Item.SubItems.Add(firstName);
            e.Item.SubItems.Add(middleInitial + ".");
            e.Item.SubItems.Add(age);
            e.Item.SubItems.Add(address + ".");
            e.Item.SubItems.Add(type);
            e.Item.SubItems.Add(status);

            e.Item = lvi;

        }
    }
```

Comment: e.ItemIndex.ToString converts the item index to a string; why are you passing things like *firstName* to this method?

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake on the previous code... I already removed e.ItemIndex.ToString since what I am passing is already a string....

Answer (score 0):

RetreiveVirtualItem is called for each item, and you are looping though every patient every time it is called. You overwrite e.Item each time, so each item ends up with the last set of values.

You need to check `e.ItemIndex` and only retrieve the data for that particular row.

Or maybe you don't actually want to use virtual mode, and you should just do the query once on startup and manually add them all to the list.

*Answer from before question was edited:*

Also, why are you creating two ListViewItems? I think your code should be this:

```
e.Item = new ListViewItem(patientNo);    

if (status.Equals("Yes"))
{
    e.Item.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}

e.Item.SubItems.Add(lastName);

e.Item.SubItems.Add(firstName);
e.Item.SubItems.Add(middleInitial + ".");
e.Item.SubItems.Add(age));
e.Item.SubItems.Add(address + ".");
e.Item.SubItems.Add(type);
e.Item.SubItems.Add(status);
```

Comment: yes I just made that code but it's still as the previous that the only thing being added to my listview is the last index

Comment: From the code you've shown, you're only adding one item. We need to see the loop. Can you edit the question and expand your code a bit?

Comment: And where are lastName, firstName, etc set?

Comment: I already edited the first code that I have posted with the whole method